# AJAX - Multiple Image Upload

Tags: ajax

is there any tutorial i can follow to upload multiple images to the server using ajax..  i followed this guy's tutorial but they use a database... i don't want any database.. http://www.9lessons.info/2011/08/ajax-image-upload-without-refreshing.html all i want is to upload the file to the server using ajax and use a progress bar to show the uploaded percentage.... and display those image when the upload completes... is there any tutorial that does just that... I've been `googling` for 3 hours but no luck.... any help would be appreciated... :) thanks in advance...

Comment: so basically this guy is using his server side code to store the images in a DB.  Change the server side code to do what ever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm sorry for posting that question... guess i should have searched in more deep... that guy wrote another post that solves my problem... i just had to remove the `dp.php` file and remove all the includes for that..... http://www.9lessons.info/2011/08/ajax-image-upload-without-refreshing.html